# document.location if page has class with specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I using PHPMailler and I needed to redirect the page after submitting the form and get success popup window.

When I has success result of submitting form there Sent message in popup window is displayed ( JS adding class 'msg' with value Sent).

I nedded to redirect and trying:

```
(function ($) {
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName("msg").innerHTML;
    if (text == "Sent") {
        window.location = "http://www.test.com"
    }
})(jQuery);
```

but haven't positive result. Could anybody help me?!

UPD: That answers that I have bootm should works, Sorry I think Im not clearly describe what I needed or what I have.

I have PHPMailer that if I success submiting the form return to another PHPMailer JS script code'MF000" that encoding and after that JS script add 'msg' class with 'Sent' text in popup, I need to redirect to another page instead this popup, maybe I could using some listener for 'MF000' code or something else?

Comment: Start with `console.log(text)`

Comment: Since you already using jQuery why not to use `$('.msg').html()` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName("msg").innerHTML;`

Comment: try this jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jitendratiwari/cwwr4tt6/)

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, so it won't have an `innerHTML` property. You need to access the resulting array by index. This should work, assuming you want the first matched element:

```
(function ($) {
    var text = document.getElementsByClassName("msg")[0].innerHTML.trim();
    if (text == "Sent") {
        window.location = "http://www.test.com"
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Note the use of `trim()` to remove leading/trailing whitespace which can affect the comparison check. Alternatively as you're using jQuery, you could do this:

```
(function ($) {
    var text = $(".msg").text().trim();
    if (text == "Sent") {
        window.location = "http://www.test.com"
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Also, make sure you're running your code *after* the DOM has been loaded. A closure alone won't do that job.